# buying and selling mini-simulator

Tags: c++, math, simulation

```
void test(){
    double money = 10000;
    double price = 0;
    int supply = 101;
    price = static_cast<double>(100) / supply;
    //buying
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        price = static_cast<double>(100) / supply;
        money -= price;
        supply--;
    }
    //selling
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        price = static_cast<double>(100) / supply;
        money += price;
        supply++;
    }
    cout << money << endl;
}
```

the code above calculates a price for a product based on its availability and then it "buys", decreasing the good´s supply and the client´s money, one of them at a time while recalculating the good´s price after every purchase. A similar process occurs when the client decides to sell the product. The glicth here is the output: the money variable´s last value is 10099 instead of the expected 10000. How would you fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `static_cast<double>(100)` instead of simply `100.0?`

Comment: I think you have to put `supply++` at the top of the second loop

Comment: for clarity, its just my style.

Comment: yes it did work, but why does it work?

Comment: By working through the calculations on paper. Not by getting someone else to do that for me for free..

Comment: my brain just couldnt wrap around it, I´m guessing programming isn`t a viable porffesion for me :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when the last item is bought, it is bought at the price appropriate for a supply of `N`. Then supply is decremented to `N - 1`. The first item to be sold is then sold for the price which is appropriate for a supply of `N - 1`. Repeat this problem 100 times, and that explains your difference.

If you want items to be sold for the same price they were bought at, then you should increment `supply` before the price calculation in the sell loop.

Comment: almost a good explanation. He has 99 too much in the end and not 100. So this explains the difference -1 ;)

Comment: From the question it seems that he _wants_ the price recalculated (_"one of them at a time while recalculating the good´s price after every purchase"_). Indeed, that's often how the real world works, too. Are you sure this is the bug?

Comment: @tobi303: Each sell transaction does not result in a profit of 1. It results in a profit of `(100/(supply - 1)) - (100/(supply))`, and supply is constantly changing, so why would you expect the difference to be 100?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, I am not sure this is a bug. Just explaining the difference from the OP's stated expected results.